# Will installing the Visual Studio 2010 +Oslo CTP screw my Visual Studio 08 install?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio

I'm eager to give these a go, but I've only got my precious home machine to try it out.

I'm in the middle of some important work that can't get inferred with, yet I can't resist the urge to give the new bits a go.

Will installing VS10 on a Vista SP1 box with VS08 screw with the VS08 experience in any way?

Comment: My advice - don't do it until you finish whatever it is you are doing. Then back everything up before doing anything.
If it was me I would run it up on Virtual PC (or VMWare) first - not an absolute guarantee but a good indicator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The download for the CTP is in the form of a Virtual PC Image, so will have no impact.

Comment: Agreed, this is the ONLY way to go with trying out a CTP of VS 2010.

Comment: Ah - in that case ignore my previous comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid installing anything tagged CTP, RC or beta on a machine you consider mission critical. Resist the temptation and install it in a VM or non-critical box instead. :)